# Как настроить панель Back/Home/Menu?

Tags: java, android

Программа выводит на экран игровую графику. Для того, чтобы графика занимала весь экран я написал

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Верхние панели исчезли, но панель Back/Home/Menu остаётся на экране и становится непрозрачной (белый цвет). Подскажите, как сделать эту панель прозрачной и убираемой. Чтобы она автоматически уползала и появлялась когда я её вытаскиваю?

Comment: Мне кажется дело в эмуляторе, если вы там запускаете. М эта часть неубирается

Comment: Нет, я запускаю на смартфоне. Если я на нём запускаю какую-нибудь игру панель Back/Home/Menu уползает и появляется если я её вытаскиваю.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive